# How can I search in Google for specific domain?

Tags: google-search, blog

If I want to get all blog lists which have domain called : `wordpress.com` then how can I search , is there any trick?

I want to search all blogs which have above domain so result output should be:

```
example1.wordpress.com

example2.wordpress.com

example3.wordpress.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`site:*.wordpress.com inurl:*.wordpress.com`

These are advanced search operators.

The `site:` search operator limits the scope for a search for the website. I used `*` as a wildcard because you are looking for subdomains, but for this example `site:wordpress.com` works equally well.

The `inurl:.wordpress.com` is specifically to serve your use case - to look specifically for subdomains (and therefore disqualify the root domain) ensure that the url structure must contain `.wordpress.com`.

Comment: Wow , thanks for quick answer and detailed answer. Its working..

Comment: Glad to help - list building is an essential skill for research, online marketing or even just sales. 

Understanding Google Operators make this easy and automatic. If you develop the skills to identify footprints and patterns on the fly, the world is your oyster.

Comment: Yes , right. I agree with you..